# Multi-line (wrapped text) in bibliography labels using shorthand for CV

Tags: biblatex, biber, wrap, shorthands

In my CV, I want to create a list of my publications. I managed to change the label of each entry to be the name of the conference using the **shorthand** field. However, for certain publications, there are special notes I want to add to the label (e.g., submitted, under review, best paper etc.) such that it appears under the conference name. Is there any way to be able to do some sort of wrapping by fixing the column length?

Here is what I currently have:

[image: current using shorthand]

The corresponding code for it is as follows. I'm using the moderncv template, but I think you can use anything.

```
\documentclass[11pt,letter,sans]{moderncv}
\moderncvstyle{casual}

\usepackage[backend=biber, defernumbers=true, maxnames=10,sorting=ydnt]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{test.bib}

\DeclareFieldFormat{labelnumberwidth}{{#1}}

\nocite{*}
\name{John}{Doe}

\begin{document}
\makecvtitle

\section{Publications} 
\vspace{0.2cm}
\printbibliography[title={Refereed Conference Publications}, heading=subbibliography, type=inproceedings, resetnumbers=true]
\end{document}
```

Then, I would have the following (and similar) entries in test.bib

```
@inproceedings{test,
author = {John Smith and John Doe},
title = {A very cool title},
booktitle = {Proceedings of the 1st Conference on Cool Things},
series = {COOL '09},
shorthand = {COOL '09},
year = {2009},
location = {Ontario, Canada},
pages = {1--11},
addendum={(Acceptance Rate: 22/88 = 25\%). \emph{\textbf{Best Paper     Award}}},
numpages = {11},
}
```

Here is what i want to achieve, but I couldn't do it directly from within biber (I'm using biber as a backend for other reasons) so I resorted to do it it through a table. As you can see there is spacing/alignment issues:

[image: goal that is not properly aligned yet]

Here is the code I use (would add it in the tex file above). I first create a new command:

```
\newcommand{\createlabel}[2]{\begin{tabular}{p{2.43cm}}
#1\\\textbf{#2}
\end{tabular}}
```

Then in the bib entry, I use this command as follows:

```
@inproceedings{test,
author = {John Smith and John Doe},
title = {A very cool title},
booktitle = {Proceedings of the 1st Conference on Cool Things},
series = {COOL '09},
shorthand = {\createlabel{COOL '09}{best paper}},
year = {2009},
location = {Ontario, Canada},
pages = {1--11},
addendum={(Acceptance Rate: 22/88 = 25\%). \emph{\textbf{Best Paper     Award}}},
numpages = {11},
}
```

Any way to fix the alignment/spacing or a smarter way to do the whole thing would be highly appreciated.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with `\documentclass{...}`, the required `\usepackage`'s, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}`. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Comment: By the way, have you tried to `\smash` the label?

Comment: Thanks Astrinus. I updated the code. No, I was not familiar with \smash. I'll try it out in the tabular environment, but not sure if it would work.

Comment: I just tried it. It did help with that extra empty line (thanks!) but now the label and the citation are not vertically aligned.

Comment: Are you satisfied with the answer below?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
\newcommand{\createlabel}[2]{\smash{\begin{tabular}[t]{p{2.43cm}}%
#1\\\textbf{#2}%
\end{tabular}}}
```

The `[t]` option of `tabular` tells LaTeX to align at top.
By the way, your MWE doesn't compile and doesn't show the reference since it misses a `\nocite{test}` in the body and `\name{John}{Doe}` in the preamble.

Comment: Thank you! That solves my problem! I changed the alignment to `r` instead of `p{2.43}` to get the right alignment though. I previously used p because I was trying to enforce text wrapping instead of using a new line. Sorry, can't up-vote your answer as I don't have the necessary reputation level yet.

Comment: Don't worry, you could accept it anyway. By the way, that can cause problem if the right block has only one line, because `\smash` tells LaTeX to ignore the height of box, that is, to pretend that the box has 0 height.